# How to see if any fields have had values changed, warn user of unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, forms, post

Working on a rather large custom backend system that we've made for a local Chamber of Commerce and one of the things we need is to halt them from clicking on sub-form links (that post on a separate page) to populate content and lose the changes or information they've entered up until that point.

The forms are rather large, 30 or more fields generally. Previously I simply did a check using Coldfusion by passing a simple variable in the url based on what kind of page they were on (New vs Edit) but obviously as things grew more sophisticated this kind of basic approach was unsatisfactory.

It has to be dynamic.

So basically, if the user makes any changes on an edit page and attempts to click "add new address" in the business address section it will detect the changes made (hard part), and will disable the link (which is the easy part) to add a new address until he saves the main form by doing a submit (which loops back to the same page).

Simply using the onChange attributes for the fields won't work, as quite a few are already using this for some function or another.

I've tried messing with a few different scripts out there, many of them involving the $(":input") filter.

This fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AFahj/50/

```
var propertyChangeUnbound = false;
$("#testbox").on("propertychange", function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == "value") {
        alert("Value changed!");
    }
});

$("#testbox").on("input", function() {
    if (!propertyChangeUnbound) {
        $("#testbox").unbind("propertychange");
        propertyChangeUnbound = true;
    }
    alert("Value changed!");
});
```

This fiddle code is broken into two parts. One for more modern browsers (lower) and older pre IE9 crap (upper).

It demonstrates the basic functionally I'm wanting, but the issue is the scope of the forms themselves. They're massive. I need something that is flexible enough to run out and grab all of the inputs in a single script and be ready to perform an action based on changes.

So how would I create a single script that can watch if any of the inputs have been edited (even if there are alot of them) and perform an appropriate action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's pseudo-selector [**`:input`**](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) is your friend here.

It selects all form inputs, including select boxes, textareas, and other inputs.

In the past I've used a snippet like this.

```
   // give 500 ms delay before detecting changes to allow
   // allow programmatic changes to input values
   setTimeout(function() {
           $(":input").on('keydown change', function(e) {
                   // when the change happens attach your event to deal with it
                   $(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
                           return "It seems you have unsaved changes.  If you continue they will be lost";
                   });

                   // then remove the change detection (since we know it has changed already
                   $(":input").off('keydown change');
           });

           // Allow the thing to happen in certain circumstances.
           $("form").on('submit', function() {
                   $(window).off('beforeunload');
           });
   }, 500);
```